# django-allauth password in email confirmation

Tags: security, passwords, django-allauth

I need send the password in the email confirmation after user signs up. 
How can I include the raw password in the context? Is it secure to pass password this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never share or store passwords in plain text because you enable anyone to read them. In addition to that, email is not a trusted channel to send sensitive information, so sending a plain text password in an email is not secure.

This post gives more details on this topic: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17979/is-sending-password-to-user-email-secure

Answer (score 2):

Why would you need to do that? It is very bad practice. If the user has forgotten their password, they can change it by receiving an email with a link.